# Bash exit doesn't exit

Tags: bash, exit, nested-loops, abort

I wonder why this script continues to run even with an explicit exit command.

I have two files:

`file1.txt` with the following content:

```
aaaaaa
bbbbbb
cccccc
dddddd
eeeeee
ffffff
gggggg
```

`file2.txt` with the following content:

```
111111
aaaaaa
222222
333333
ffffff
444444
```

The script (`test.sh`) is this, two nested loops checking if any line of the first file contains any line of the second file. If it finds a match, it aborts.

```
#!/bin/bash
path=`dirname $0`

cat $path/file1.txt | while read line
do  
    echo $line
    cat $RUTA/file2.txt | while read another
    do
        if [ ! -z "`echo $line | grep -i $another`" ]; then
            echo "!!!!!!!!!!"
            exit 0
        fi              
    done
done
```

I get the following output even when it should exit after printing the first `!!!!!!!!!!`:

```
aaaaaa
!!!!!!!!!!
bbbbbb
cccccc
dddddd
eeeeee
ffffff
!!!!!!!!!!
gggggg
```

**Isn't `exit` supposed to end the execution of the script altogether?**

Comment: The only reason I can think of is due to the pipe into `while`. The pipe will kick off another subprocess (shell) for the `while`, so the `exit` within the `while` exits that shell and your back to your original.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The reason is that the pipes create sub processes. Use input redirection instead and it should work

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line
do
    echo "$line"
     while read -r another
    do
        if  grep -i "$another" <<< "$line" ;then
            echo "!!!!!!!!!!"
            exit 0
        fi
    done < file2.txt
done < file1.txt
```

In the general case, where the input comes from another program and not from a file, you can use [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html)

```
while read -r line
do
    echo "$line"
     while read -r another
    do
        if  grep -i "$another" <<< "$line" ;then
            echo "!!!!!!!!!!"
            exit 0
        fi
    done < <(command2)
done < <(command1)
```

Comment: Thanks... What if instead of files I need to compare the output of too commands ? How could I use input redirection with that ? I tried <<< command but it didn't work... I happened to use the file1 file2 example in order to simplify the question, but I'm really comparing the output of two commands.

Comment: Then you should use [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html). For example: `while read -r line; do #commands; done < <(othercommand)`

Comment: You blew me away! Bash is so idiomatic.

Comment: Helped me so much! Had a cat file | to a while loop and it just did not want to exit the script. It would exit the loop only. Switched to input redirect and the exit worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The while loops are running in their respective shells. Exiting one shell does not exit the containing ones. $? could be your friend here:

```
            ...
            echo "!!!!!!!!!!"
            exit 1
        fi
    done
    [ $? == 1 ] && exit 0;
done
```